# Cannot detect my AVD comes online

Tags: android, android-studio, connection

I recently upgraded my SDK for my AVD and the files seems corrupted. It takes forever to say "waiting for target device to come online" even if my device already online. I tried that on my actual phone and saw the same issue. I tried delete and recreated the AVD, reinstall API 27 but still couldn't solve the problem. But I believe it shouldn't be the problem of my AVD because my actual phone shows the same problem as well.

Comment: Did u activated the dubugger mode?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by cleaning the program and rebuilt it.